# angular 2 router error: router_1.provideRouter is not a function

Tags: angular, router

I get error `router_1.provideRouter is not a function` when I use provideRouter function in bootstrap.

> angular2-polyfills.js:349           Error: router_1.provideRouter is not a
>   function(…)

here is my boot.ts code:

```
import {bootstrap}                     from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent}                  from './app.component';
import {Dashboard1Component}           from './dashboard1.component'
import {TextAreaComponent}             from './textArea.component'
import { provideRouter }               from 'angular2/router';
const router =[
  { path: 'link1', component: TextAreaComponent },
  { path: 'link2', component: Dashboard1Component }
];

bootstrap(AppComponent,[provideRouter(router)]).catch(err => console.error(err));;
```

and here is my script in index.html to load app and libs without using system.config.js:

```
<!-- Angular 2 beta parts -->
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.17/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.17/router.dev.js"></script>


<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
    packages: {'components': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}}
  });
  System.import('components/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Note that I don't have router_1 variable anywhere in my code. I appreciate guidance. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`provideRouter` was introduced with the new router shipped with `RC.3` and was not available in beta.17

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Could you direct me where can I find RC.3 version of router please?
according https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2 beta 17 is the latest release, and I cannot find RC3 versions in other CDN as well.

Comment: The namespace was changed from `angular2` to `@angular` with RC.0

Comment: `npm install --save @angular/core @angular/compiler @angular/common @angular/platform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 zone.js@0.6.12`  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem, as someone else stated, the modules are in bundles so you have to update:
**systemjs.config.js**

```
var map = {
    '@angular/router':  'node_modules/@angular/router'
}
```

also the **app.routes.ts**

```
import { provideRouter }    from '@angular/router';
import { RouterConfig }     from  '@angular/router';
```